# How can I know the names of the files / archives that I loaded into a vault?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I wish to load my zipped folders into the amazon glacier.
It seems that after loading files / archives into a vault, I can only get information about **how many** archives I have in the vault.

How can I know the **names of the files / archives** that I have in the vault?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the files within the zip files, then you have to track that yourself.

If you are talking about the archives themselves, then amazon provides [inventory data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/vault-inventory.html) that you can get these via the [InitiateJob](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-initiate-job-post.html) api. As always retrievals take several hours, and this inventory data is only updated once a day or so.

You may also consider storing files in S3 (with the storage type set to GLACIER): This allows all the convenience of the regular apis for browsing bucket contents but with glacier pricing for the storage.